# I have a variable number of textboxes how do I retrieve their values in a servlet

Tags: java, forms, servlets, textbox

I have a number of textboxes that will be displayed with their existing values. I want my servlet to be able to get all their values and then update the database with the the values that have changed.

How do I get the values? Is there some way to put them into a HashMap with the id or name as the key and the value of the textbox as the value for the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're giving all of the text boxes the same name, you can get a `String[]` of the values via [`ServletRequest.getParameterValues`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues(java.lang.String)).

If you want to get all of your submitted fields in a single map, you can use [`ServletRequest.getParameterMap`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap()) to get a `Map` of all of the parameters submitted. Each individual parameter's value in the map is a `String[]`.

Here's some sample code that walks through all submitted parameters and all of their values:

```
Iterator    it;
Map         params;
String      name;
String[]    values;
int         n;

params = request.getParameterMap();
it = params.keySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{
    name = (String)it.next();
    values = (String[])params.get(name);
    for (n = 0; n < values.length; ++n)
    {
        // ...use value[n]...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... I probably should have googled a little more first.

Comment: @Ankur: No worries, hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use [`HttpServletRequest.getParameterValues("someName")`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29) where all text inputs have `name="someName"`

Comment: LOL Jinx! Just got back from adding that to my answer (since he'd said it was a bunch of text boxes) and saw your post.